# Twitter tmhOAuth - problems uploading image to user page

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, image-uploading

I am using tmhOAuth from https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth, and trying to upload an image from my website to the user's Twitter page. The response on callback.php is 200 (Success), but there is nothing on the user's page. The App has r/w permissions, and "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" checked. Anyone has an idea? I am using 2 PHP files:

**twitter.php**

```
include("tmhOAuth.php");
include("tmhUtilities.php");
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
'consumer_key' => 'abcd123',
'consumer_secret' => 'xyz',
'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => false
));
$tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/request_token', ''));
$response = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response["response"]);
$temp_token = $response['oauth_token']; 
$temp_secret = $response['oauth_token_secret']; 
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
setcookie("Temp_Token", $temp_token, $time + 3600 * 30, '/');
setcookie("Temp_Secret", $temp_secret, $time + 3600 * 30, '/');
setcookie("Tweet_Txt", 'Share your AFA stand!', $time + 3600 * 30, '/');
setcookie("Img_Url", 'success', $time + 3600 * 30, '/');
$url = $tmhOAuth->url("oauth/authorize", "") . '?oauth_token=' . $temp_token;
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Post this image on Twitter</a>';
```

**callback.php**

```
define("CONSUMER_KEY", "abcd123");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "xyz");
include("tmhOAuth.php");
include("tmhUtilities.php");
$token = $_COOKIE['Temp_Token'];
$secret = $_COOKIE['Temp_Secret'];
$txt = $_COOKIE['Tweet_Txt'];
$img = base64_encode(file_get_contents('wide/achievement.jpg'));
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
'consumer_key' => CONSUMER_KEY,
'consumer_secret' => CONSUMER_SECRET,
'user_token' => $token,
'user_secret' => $secret, 
'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => false
));
$tmhOAuth->request("POST", $tmhOAuth->url("oauth/access_token", ""), array(  
    'oauth_verifier' => $_GET["oauth_verifier"] 
)); 
$response = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response["response"]);
$tmhOAuth->config["user_token"] = $response['oauth_token']; 
$tmhOAuth->config["user_secret"] = $response['oauth_token_secret'];

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json',
array(
    'media_data' => $img,
    'status' => $txt
),
true, // use auth
true // multipart
);
if ($code == 200){
    echo '<h1>Your image tweet has been sent successfully</h1>';
}else{
    echo $code;
    echo "failed<br />";
    tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}
```

I am getting "Your image tweet has been sent successfully", but it is not actually posted. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to change the API url to:
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json